# Stash parse categories and category_id

Tags: categories, stash, conditionals, parse

I'm trying to use the following conditionals in exp:stash:parse to set some values based on the category_id. However, I just can't get it to work and it always just gold for channel_colour or 20 for channel_category_group:

```
{exp:stash:set_list name="landing-{segment_1}" parse_tags="yes" parse_conditionals="yes" parse_depth="3" save="yes" refresh="60" scope="site" replace="yes"}
    {exp:channel:entries
        channel="landing_page"
        disable="{global:channel_disable_basic}"
        status="open"
        limit="1"
    }
        {exp:stash:parse process="inline" parse_depth="2"}
        {categories limit="1" show_group="5"}
            {if category_id == "60"}
                {exp:stash:set_value name="channel_short_name" value="things-to-do"}
                {exp:stash:set_value name="channel_url" value="things-to-do"}
                {exp:stash:set_value name="channel_category_group" value="2"}
                {exp:stash:set_value name="channel_colour" value="blue"}
            {if:elseif category_id == "62"}
                {exp:stash:set_value name="channel_short_name" value="food-drink"}
                {exp:stash:set_value name="channel_url" value="food-drink"}
                {exp:stash:set_value name="channel_category_group" value="3"}
                {exp:stash:set_value name="channel_colour" value="red"}
            {if:elseif category_id == "61"}
                {exp:stash:set_value name="channel_short_name" value="stay"}
                {exp:stash:set_value name="channel_url" value="stay"}
                {exp:stash:set_value name="channel_category_group" value="4"}
                {exp:stash:set_value name="channel_colour" value="yellow"}
            {if:elseif category_id == "63"}
                {exp:stash:set_value name="channel_short_name" value="study"}
                {exp:stash:set_value name="channel_url" value="study"}
                {exp:stash:set_value name="channel_category_group" value="20"}
                {exp:stash:set_value name="channel_colour" value="green"}
            {if:else}
                {exp:stash:set_value name="channel_colour" value="gold"}
            {/if}
        {/categories}
        {/exp:stash:parse}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set_list}
```

Wondered if someone can help figure out what's going on?

Thanks,

Comment: What version of EE are you running? And what's in your channel:entries tag? (are you fetching multiple entries or just a single one?). How are you getting the variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Updated in light of your comment...]

The problem is that you're using pre EE2.9, where the conditional parsing was improved to avoid the advanced conditionals trap (full story here if you're not aware of it: http://derekallard.com/index.php/blog/post/simple-vs-complex-conditionals-in-expressionengine-templates)

Basically in "advanced" conditionals, all of the tags get processed first before the irrelevant sections are removed from the output.

If you can't upgrade EE you could try Croxton's `IfElse` plugin, or `Switchee`. However, upgrading would be best, as dealing with these kind of things in pre 2.9 is an exercise in frustration.

Comment: Hey @James Smith. I have updated the code above to show what I currently have with channel entries tag and set list. Essentially each page has a category assigned. Now these category names match other channel names.So I get the client to check a category so that they can indicate which Channel and colours are pulled through to this page. The coded channel_category_group relates to other category groups rather than the 5 above. I'm using EE v2.8.1 and Stash v2.5.3.